# Django query to get all ads whose keyword sets are contained by a search string

Tags: django, search, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset

I am trying to implement an advertising system in Django.  My model for ads is as follows:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    ...
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

    def keystring(self):
        keys = self.keyword.all()
        keystring_value = ""
        for key in keys:
            keystring_value = keystring_value + key.keyword_name
        keystring_value = str(keystring_value)
        return (keystring_value)
    ...
```

The relevant part here is the keyword attribute.  It is a many to many relationship with a master list of keyword objects.  So when a user searches for some set of keywords, say "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3", i want all ads with the following keyword sets to return: "keyword1 keyword2", "keyword2 keyword3", "keyword1", "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3", etc -- any ad whose keyword set is contained by the search string.  I do NOT want that search to return an ad for "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword4".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is to take the complement of your list of keywords -- that is, say after processing user input you have a list of strings like `['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3']` in a variable `keywords`. Then you take all the keywords which are not in that list:

```
disallowed_keywords = Keyword.objects.exclude(keyword_name__in=keywords)
```

And then instead of finding ads that match your wanted keywords, you exclude those that match the wrong ones:

```
Ad.objects.exclude(keyword__in=disallowed_keywords)
```

Comment: This was very nearly correct.  the disallowed_keywords filter did not take keyword_name__in=keywords as an exclusion clause -- I used pk__in=keywords instead, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I need to correct my previous comment.  The posted solution would have worked as is if I had been using a text search box, which the answerer understandably assumed I was doing.  Since its still in development, I'm working off a list based keyword selector for my search, not a text box.  That is why I had to make the change to pk in the filter.  So, the answer was not very nearly correct, it was completely correct.  Thanks again.